# local-universe, mesosphere, dc/os

Tags: dcos

I actually wanted to deploy mesosphere-universe locally with some custom packages added to it and so followed the same steps  described in https://github.com/mesosphere/universe

below are the steps i did to add custom packages and then deploy this universe package locally:

1. Forked and cloned https://github.com/mesosphere/universe
2. added two custom packages in the path repo/packages/A:- x1 (with necessary json files as described of packaging version-3), x2 (json files;packaging version-3)
3. Ran  verification build script:- scripts/build.sh
4. Did git pull origin version-3.x
5. built universe server locally :-  DOCKER_TAG="my-package" docker/server/build.bash
6. Running universe server:- 
   dcos marathon app add marathon.json
   dcos package repo add --index=0 dev-universe http://universe.marathon.mesos:8085/repo

I was able to run the universe server successfully but however i couldn't find the custom packages x1 and x2 in repo. what am i missing here? why am i not getting the packages in the local universe server?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, Marathon is trying to pull the new image but it doesn't exist thats why the new package doesn't show in the UI.

After you've created the image with

```
DOCKER_TAG="my-package" docker/server/build.bash
```

you have to publish the image so that it gets pulled by Marathon:

```
DOCKER_TAG="my-package" docker/server/build.bash publish
```

Detailed steps are listed in this blog post: https://dcos.io/blog/2016/a-developer-s-guide-to-the-universe/index.html

Comment: as you said i tried to publish the image but stuck with error:- "unauthorized: authentication required" to push the repository [docker.io/mesosphere/universe-server]. This error is usually caused if we try to access an images or push the image to docker.io as username/image_name. here mesosphere will be username hence authentication error. how to solve this error?

Comment: And also i modified line "DOCKER_IMAGE=${DOCKER_IMAGE:-"sandhya17/universe-server"} in the file "docker/server/build.bash" to refer to custom docker repo n i was able to publish images.